# Reference global variables in VBScript the same way as window["var_name"] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, reference, window

In JavaScript, I was able to access variables by using the variable name in a string in the "window" and "document" objects:

```
window["var_name"]
```

This was very useful, because I could make variable changes dynamically as long as they were members of the window or document objects.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in VBScript, and what this process was called.

Comment: If you are using `window["var_name"]` then it is a sign that you should have created an Object to play with rather then adding extra properties to the window object.

Comment: Actually I used to use it a lot to pull values from the query string and use them as variable names to set other options which are otherwise set as defaults.  In the case of VBscript, it's important that I do this for Request.Form, because the only way to get the variable name in a For Each loop is to reference the Item.Name, which is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing strictly equivalent.

If you want to dynamically access variables, you can use the Execute statement, which is similar to eval in other languages.

```
Dim x, var_name

var_name = "x"
Execute var_name & " = 10"
WScript.Echo x  '' Prints 10
```

If you want to get a reference to a Sub or Function, you can use GetRef.

```
Dim x

Set x = GetRef("my_sub")
x

Sub my_sub
    WScript.Echo "Hello, world"
End Sub
```